# How to design an HTML/CSS signature that will work in Outlook 2016?

Tags: html, css, email, signature, outlook-2016

I am currently using a HTML coded signature at the signature of my emails, however Outlook Express 2016 cannot show the following content:

```
<hr lenght="400" width="415" align="left" style="border: 3px dashed #ADADAD" color="#FFFFFF" size="0";">
```

I obviously was using inline CSS but it does not seem CSS works at Outlook 2016. However, Mozilla Thunderbird was able to show this element correctly.

I wish to insert a 400x415 dashed line in my signature at the stated colours (I want it to be gray, at least).

I just wonder if there is a workaround to get Outlook Express 2016 to show this element?  I really want my signature to be shown correctly at each email clients, especially in MS Outlook.

Likewise, I wonder if it was possible to style a `<hr>` the same way via using HTML only? (As in that case, I'm sure Outlook 2016 would be able to show this content).

Answer (score 0):

In Outlook border property does not work,It would be better to use an image with dashed lines in the needed place intead

Comment: I'm afraid that's not a solution for me as MS Outlook 2016 sends the inserted images in signatures  as attachments.

Thanks for Your input though!

Comment: I believe it could be of help to me if You were able to change the following  CSS code to in-line CSS:  <hr style="height:1px; border:none; color:#777777; background-color:#FFFFFF; width:60%; text-align:left; margin: 0 auto 0 0;">  The line should be dashed, with a width of 415 instead. Please refer to the 1st comment should you require any further information.

Comment: This would also worth a try in inline CSS:  hr.style {
 background-color: #fff;
 border-top: 2px dashed #8c8b8b;
}